# How can I return any type that implements a given trait?

Tags: rust

We have the following code:

```rust
enum Widgets {
    A,
    B,
}

trait Widget {}

struct A {}

impl A {
    fn new() -> Self {
        A {}
    }
}

impl Widget for A {}

struct B {}

impl B {
    fn new() -> Self {
        B {}
    }
}

impl Widget for B {}

struct Foo {
    widgets: Vec<Widgets>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn create_widget(self) -> impl Widget {
        match self.widgets[0] {
            Widgets::A => A::new(),
            Widgets::B => B::new(),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=76616ee972244f924923a8f74c3a0ef8)

This code fails to compile because the match arms have incompatible types. However they both implement the trait `Widget` and our function seems to be saying we'll return something that implements `Widget`.

How can we return any type that implements `Widget` from the match logic?

Comment: See also [this article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html) for what `impl trait` really means.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that article was very helpful, thank you for linking it!